# Filtering column with json data using Eloquent ORM included with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm making a data filter and I need to filter a column with json saved data. The table structure is similar to this:

```
____________________________________
| id | name    | tags              |
|____|_________|___________________|
| 1  | example | ["3","4","5","6"] |
|____|_________|___________________|
```

Any idea how to filter this column by tags using Eloquent ORM included with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the getter `get<Column>Attribute`:

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    public function getTagsAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }

}
```

Comment: And then how can I use it with Article::where('tags', '=', $tags) ?

Comment: You can create a scope similar to this that I created for you: http://laravel.io/bin/0eElj#

Comment: Caution, `$q->whereOr('tags', 'like', '%"'.$tag.'"%');` will be very slow if the table is big and a json with tags if there are many time the same tags will be very heavy. For scalability and optimization, prefer create a Tag model and a relation YourModel <- many-to-many -> Tag, so you will first get `Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)` then get YourModel ids from it in the assiociative table and YourModel objets or the equivalent join. It will be very faster with a big amount of data.

Comment: @KyleK can you give me an example for the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You could use mySql JSON_CONTAINS function since it is optimized on the DB level. Unfortunately Eloquent doesn't (?) provide wrappers for functions like this so you can fall back to plain SQL and create your models from the results.

This is an example that returns a Collection of Models:

```
class myModel extends Eloquent {

  protected   $casts = [
      'json_column' => 'array', // this is JSON type in the DB
  ];

  /**
  * Returns a Collection of 'myModel' that have $search value
  * stored in the 'json_column' array
  *
  * @param  string $search
  * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
  */
  public static function findInJsonColumn($search){
    $data = \DB::select("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_column, '[\"$search\"]')");
    return self::hydrate($data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    public function getTagsAttribute($value)
    {
        parent::where($value)->get();
    }

}
```